# Type inference with lazy initialization and generic factory method in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, type-inference, factory-method

I have a factory method that produces some list of `<T>`:

```
inline fun <reified T> getObject(fileName: String): List<T>
```

The factory method should be used for lazy initialization like this:

```
val points: List<Point> by lazy {
    ObjectFactory.getObject(pointsFileName)
}
```

Now the Kotlin compiler obviously has not enough type information inside the lambda and complains:

```
Type inference failed:
Not enough information to infer parameter T in
inline fun <reified T> getObject(fileName: String): List<T>
Please specify it explicitly.
```

The compiler is not considering the type to which the result of the lazy initialization will be assigned. I can work around this by providing the type locally, but it's not pretty:

```
val points by lazy {
    val pointsToCommunicateType: List<Point> =
            ObjectFactory.getObject(pointsFileName)
    pointsToCommunicateType
}
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the type like this:

```
ObjectFactory.getObject<Point>(pointsFileName)
```